# Problem integrating two react projects: blocked javascrpit import in index.hml

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am using airframe react dashboard as the boilerplate for my project ( https://github.com/0wczar/airframe-react ) and now I need to add ZOOM web sdk into it, zoom provided a sample react project that works just fine on its own ( https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-web local version from Local folder )

For the zoom sdk to work it needs to import some javascripts (check out the index.html file) and when copying over the needed scripts chrome is throwing the following error for each of the files imported:

```
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/react/umd/react.production.min.js”. consult:165:1
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js”. consult:166:1
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js”. consult:167:1
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/redux-thunk/dist/redux-thunk.min.js”. consult:168:1
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js”. consult:169:1
The resource from “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://0.0.0.0:4100/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js”.
```

I have a feeling this is to do with webpack from the host project (airframe, the one I'm trying to import the sdk sample into)

I found some instructions on webpack documentation to import jquery globally in weback for example but it did not work, so I'm not sure that's really the problem.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
```

Could someone help pointing me in the right direction since I don't have to knowledge to understand why there scripts are being blocked, all I find on google is regarding CSS and not js modules

Comment: Are you running a web server on localhost:4100?

Comment: @SydneyY not exactly, its 0.0.0.0:4100. But how would that be important?

Comment: This error is the browser saying that it sent a GET request to 0.0.0.0:4100 for the file /node_modules/.../react.production.min.css, etc, and it got HTML back. That HTML is likely a 404 error page saying the server couldn't find that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the zoom sample app it would seem that you could skip adding the scripts and add the following to your package.json file in your airframe project:

```
"dependencies": { // add to your existing dependencies object, don't make a new one
    "@zoomus/websdk": "^1.7.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "7.1.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
  },
```

And in your React file that uses the Zoom Meeting SDK just import it:

```
import {ZoomMtg} from '@zoomus/websdk';
```

Remember to run an npm install after updating the package.json, and watch that you don't add duplicates. If there is a duplicate keep the one with the higher version number, in most cases.

Comment: That worked, but for some reason jQuery still needed to be imported in the index.html, or else the global $ could not be found.
Thanks Sydney